# Что является аналогом OPTIMIZE TABLE для InnoDB таблиц

Tags: mysql, innodb

Для MyISAM таблиц использовал

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE  t1
```

Для InnoDB читаю, что это

```
ALTER TABLE t1 ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

но в разделе [Maintenance of Partitions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-maintenance.html) приводится пример расширенных команд

Какую(ие) точно команду(ы) использовать чтобы оптимизировать таблицу после удаление/изменения существенного кол-ва данных таблицы InnoDB?

Comment: Ну вроде как так же https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-storage-layout.html  А раздел документации о partitions вам скорее всего вообще не нужен. Или вы используете партиционирование ? https://habrahabr.ru/post/66151/

Comment: @Mike, нет, не использую.

Comment: Такое точно работает с версии 5.0. В InnoDB до версии 5.5 работает как ALTER TABLE ..., с версии 5.5 работает как ALTER TABLE ... FORCE. FORCE означает, что страницу нужно просто перестроить заново. До версии 5.5 FORCE принимался, но игнорировался.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Ответ из комментариев*

Для InnoDB так же используется оператор `OPTIMIZE TABLE`.